# Does the word בָּר mean corn?

Tags: food, translation, book-of-amos

What is the proper translation of the word בָּר found for example in Amos 8:5. I have seen it [translated as corn](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1508.htm) which I do not understand both because corn did not exist outside of the western hemisphere at that time and because the [very same site](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0127.htm) translates דָּגָן as corn elsewhere. If  בָּר does not mean corn, what does it mean?

Comment: "Corn" doesn't mean corn. It's an archaic form of the word "grain".

Comment: It's probably an unidentified species of grain.

Comment: בר means wild, thus this may refer to an undomesticated (i.e. lower quality) grain.

Answer (score 15):

In British English, "corn" can mean any grain, not just maize (the plant native to America). See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corn); [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corn#Noun).

Comment: that's what I assumed but then it is odd for them to choose corn as the translation and it also puts into question the difference between all the many words for grain like שֶּׁבֶר found earlier in the same pasuk

Comment: It's likely a relic of KJV which strongly influenced JPS.  See http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/poly/amo008.htm